# Files Stored under Document tab

Tags: document

Is it possible to associate files stored under document tab with different records say with account record.

I know that the files which are stored using chatter can be shared with records but is it possible with document related files also?

Answer (score 1):

No. Documents are free floating files with no specific relationship to anything. It was, and still is, a way to store multipurpose documents, such as app and letterhead logos, email attachments, training and marketing material (and related uses), and images to include in email templates (external images).

Outside of these uses, it has been superseded by Content, Files, and Chatter.